# How can I use variable value to give space

Tags: c++, printf

I want to give space equal to number of digit in n variable. But cant find any way to do it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include<stdio.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    int n,i;
    cin>>n;
    while(n!=0){
        n/=10;
        i++;
    }
    printf("%id hello world",i);//want to give space equal to digit of n
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: give space? Do you mean you want output be eg `"  hello world"` when a two digit number is entered?

Comment: yes.this is what i want to do

Comment: you wrote a loop that increments `i`, the loop has as many iterations as the input number has digits. Hint: Do you know how to print a single space ?

Comment: %1d?? i want to put in variable value between % and d

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25609500/2027196

Comment: You can add `fputc(' ',stdout);` to your `while` loop [with just: `printf("hello world\n");`] Or ... you can do: `printf("%*.shello world\n",i,"");`

Comment: Since you are programming in C++, take a look at `std::cout` and the `width` member function as well reading the chapter about I/O manipulators.